# Connect FreeNAS to AD on Windows Server 2016

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, truenas

I have configured DNS, NPT and active directory services on my server but I'm still struggling to connect FreeNAS to a domain. There is no firewall between these two. I've created a freenasAdmin user and added a new computer with all the necessary privileges. There is no adminui nor nis feature anymore in 2016 so I'm not quite sure I did it right. All the FreeNAS throws at me is can't connect o ldap connection timeout.

Comment: When a computer (=FN Device) is joining the domain, the computer account is created automatically; so just delete you existing machine account (or set is to 'trust'). If the FN Machine says 'no connection to LDAP' check this by yourself first.

Comment: "There is no adminui nor nis feature anymore in 2016"  WHAT?

Comment: @JBaldridge https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/activedirectoryua/2016/02/09/identity-management-for-unix-idmu-is-deprecated-in-windows-server/

Comment: I apologize, I have not worked with *nix joined domain machines.  I was not aware that there was a dedicated *nix gui surfaced at one point.  However it looks like you can just move over to using Active Directory Administrative Center to edit the attributes the deprecated *nix gui edited.

Comment: @JBaldridge you don't need to apologize....I don't know why bud I had to manually set the FQDN of DC and GC to use with FreeNAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have a working Windows 2016 DC so I won't go into that.

In FreeNAS go to directory services -> active directory and click Advanced Mode.

- Enter your domain name, Domain acc. and password (I used
  Administrator acc)
- uncheck UNIX extensions
- enter your site name (this can be found in server manager -> Tools -> Active Directory Sites and Services)
- enter FQDN of your DC and GC
- set Idmap backend to rip and SASL wrapping to sign
- check enable
- enter netBIOS name capitalized and hit save